# How to select random 5 value from array value of 100 in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have 100 values in an array but I need to select 5 value randomly on every click one button and I have one value e.g a=10 this a value shouldn't come in the 5 selected value.

I tried in different way but I am not able to do it in jquery. please any help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code may help. The calculateRandoms function calculates 5 different random numbers from the numbers array each time. The random number cannot be value of excludedNumber. You can change  randomCount variable to modify the number of random numbers that calculateRandoms will generate.

```js
var excludedNumber = 10;
var randomCount = 5;
var numbers = [];
var randoms = [];
var vPool="";

// initialize array, fill it from 0 to 99
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) numbers.push(i + 1);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        calculateRandoms(randomCount);             
    });
});
function calculateRandoms(c) { 
    randoms = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        var rnd = excludedNumber;
        while (rnd == excludedNumber && $.inArray(rnd, numbers)){
            rnd = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
            randoms.push(rnd);
        }
    }
    vPool='';
    $.each(randoms, function(i, val) {  
        vPool+=val + "<br />";
        $("#res").html(vPool);
    });
    //alert(randoms);
    //$("#res").html(randoms);
    //console.log(randoms);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Generate" />
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, calculateRandoms uses the method, jquery.inArray to look up for a value in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno, if it strictly needs to be jQuery, but here is a pure JS solution.
"input" is the array holding the 100 values.

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < 5; ++i) {
 var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * input.length);

 if (input[randomIndex] != 10) {
  output.push(input[randomIndex);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also resort randomly the original array

```
function reorder(src) {
    return src.sort(function (a, b) { return 1 - (Math.random() * 2); });
}
```

and you can get the top 5 like this:

```
yourArray = reorder(yourArray).slice(0, 5);
```